# When is Connection object picked up and released in JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am assuming that a `JdbcTemplate` object while processing below method, performs:
-picks up `Connection` object from connection pool.
-create `Statment` object.
-execute sql query.
-release `Connection` object.

```
jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(..);
```

Could you please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out `JdbcTemplate`'s [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#JdbcTemplate.update%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator%2Corg.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter%29)

The `execute()` method :
-picks up Connection object from connection pool.
-create Statment object.
-execute sql query.
-release Connection object.

Method's like `update`, `queryForObject` internally call `execute()`